# How to only show reports for those with a remaining balance

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've created a statement report that pulls from a query of a couple tables and groups them by ClientID and a couple sorts and each client has their statement on a separate page with their total owed.

The issue is that it shows clients that currently owe nothing and I only wish to print statements where their summed ChargeAmt is greater than zero. I cannot seem to be able to use Totals with a sum on the ChargeAmt since it just shows me the sum. Even when adding ChargeAmt again with the GroupBy option, it will continue to only show the summed value.

```
SELECT ChargeAccount.ClientID, Sale.SaleNo, Sale.SaleDate, Sale.LastName, ChargeAccount.ChargeAmt, Sale.FirstName, Sale.MI, Sale.StreetAddress, Sale.City, Sale.State, Sale.ZipCode, Sale.SaleTotal, ChargeAccount.ChDate
FROM ChargeAccount INNER JOIN
     Sale
     ON ChargeAccount.SaleNo = Sale.SaleNo
WHERE (((ChargeAccount.ChargeAmt)<>0))
ORDER BY Sale.LastName, ChargeAccount.ChargeAmt DESC;
```

Can I add a SUM function, maybe within a HAVING clause or something? I'm very new to this so I apologize if this is a simple matter.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't think it would be necessary in this case. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest joining your query to an aggregated subquery which returns the `ClientID` for those accounts for which the `SUM` of `ChargeAmt` is non-zero.

This removes the need for your `WHERE` clause as the selection criteria is implicit in the `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    ChargeAccount.ClientID, 
    Sale.SaleNo, 
    Sale.SaleDate, 
    Sale.LastName, 
    ChargeAccount.ChargeAmt, 
    Sale.FirstName, 
    Sale.MI, 
    Sale.StreetAddress, 
    Sale.City,
    Sale.State, 
    Sale.ZipCode, 
    Sale.SaleTotal, 
    ChargeAccount.ChDate
FROM 
    (ChargeAccount INNER JOIN Sale ON ChargeAccount.SaleNo = Sale.SaleNo) 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT t.ClientID
        FROM ChargeAccount t
        GROUP BY t.ClientID
        HAVING SUM(t.ChargeAmt) <> 0
    ) s ON ChargeAccount.ClientID = s.ClientID
ORDER BY 
    Sale.LastName, ChargeAccount.ChargeAmt DESC;
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you very much. I did leave the WHERE clause though because I had a dummy line in the table I couldn't get rid of due to a form issue I couldn't resolve. That clause was simply to leave out any ChargeAmt's of 0. Thanks again!